# Exchange of bounded linear functional and sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

I am currently in front of this exercise :

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be an arbitrary Banach space, let $\{x_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{X}$ be a sequence such that $x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n$ converges in $\mathcal{X}$. Let $\varphi \in \mathcal{X}^*$ be a bounded, linear functional on $\mathcal{X}$.

1. Show that $\varphi(x) = \varphi \left ( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n \right ) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \varphi (x_n)$
2. Give a concrete example which shows that the converse is not true in general, i.e. there exist sequences $\{x_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subset \mathcal{X}$ such that $\varphi(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \varphi (x_n)$ converges in $\mathbb{C}$ but such that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n$ does not converge in $\mathcal{X}$.

My question is twofold :

**First**, I'd like to know whether my answer to task 1. is indeed correct. I simply applied the linearity property of $\varphi$, i.e.
$\varphi(x) = \varphi \left ( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n \right ) = \varphi (x_1 + x_2 + ...) = \varphi(x_1) + \varphi(x_2) + \varphi(x_3) + ... = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \varphi(x_n) $

I assume that linearity does not destroy the general convergence in this case. Thus, this must be correct.

**Second**, I am quite stuck on task 2. My first attempt was to use a sequence which is known to be non-convergent, for example $x_n = (-1)^n$ and argue that we can find a bounded, linear functional s.t. it fixes the convergence. Is this a rightful approach and if so, how could such a linear functional look like? Maybe I am on the wrong path, though!

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: No, you're _not_ just applying linearity in the first part! Linearity says nothing about infinite sums. Linearity shows that $\phi(x_1+\dots+x_n)=\phi(x_1)+\dots+\phi(x_n)$; now you have to deduce the result for infinite sums from that

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First case: Well what you wrote is kind of correct but I believe the rigorous way to do this as follows. Define $\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n=s_n$, clearly $s_n\to \sum_{n=1}^\infty= x_n=x$. Since $\varphi$ is bounded linear operator it is continuous. Therefore $\lim\varphi(s_n)=\varphi(x)$. By definition and linearity we have $\lim \varphi(s_n)=\lim \sum_{n=1}^N\varphi(x_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\varphi(x_n) $
- Consider the linear functional $\phi: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by $\phi(x,y)=x$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining task 1! I have understood the implication to expand this for infinite sums also thanks to David in above comment! 

Regarding your proposed functional $\phi$, I am not sure if I understand. Am I correct in assuming this :

$\phi(x, y) = \sum_n \phi(x_n, y_n) = \sum_n x_n$ converges if $x_n \rightarrow x \in \mathcal{X}$ (some arbitrary sequence which converges)

But, we could have that
$y = \sum_n y_n$ does not converge?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. For example if $x_n= (0,n)$. Then the sum,  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (0,n)$, clearly diverges to infinity. But $\phi\left( (0,n)\right) =0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! :-)